# How can I append data to a std::string in hex format?

Tags: c++, string

I have an existing `std::string` and an `int`. I'd like to concatenate the ASCII (string literal) hexadecimal representation of the integer to the `std::string`.

**For example**:

```
 std::string msg = "Your Id Number is: ";
 unsigned int num = 0xdeadc0de; //3735929054
```

**Desired string**:

```
std::string output = "Your Id Number is: 0xdeadc0de";
```

Normally, I'd just use printf, but I can't do this with a std::string (can I?)

Any suggestions as to how to do this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use a stringstream.  You can use it as any other output stream, so you can equally insert `std::hex` into it.  Then extract it's `stringstream::str()` function.

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "your id is " << std::hex << 0x0daffa0;
const std::string s = ss.str();
```

Comment: Building on xtofl's answer, the header you're looking for is `<iomanip>`. This is where `std::hex`, `std::dec`, and `std::oct` live, all of which can be directed into streams such that whatever gets sent into the stream after them is converted to that base.

Comment: std::showbase should be used in addition to std::hex to exactly match the OP's requirement of prefixing the int's representation with "0x"

Answer (score -2):

I believe 'string' only forward declares std::stringstream. So you also need to include:

```
#include <sstream>
```

Comment: Including stringstream will not solve the parsing of number to string.