# How to convert a pointer value to QString?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qstring

for debug purposes I often output pointer values (mostly `this`) to qDebug:

`qDebug("pointer of current object = 0x%08x",this);`, using "%08x" as format string and simply passing `this` as a parameter.

How can I convert the pointer value to a QString?

This is what I got so far:

```
char p = (char)this;
return QString("0x%1").arg(p, 8, '0');
```

But the compiler doesn't seem to figure out what to do with that value. Is casting to `char` correct in this case? Or what would be a safer way to do this?

Using Visual C++ with Qt 4.7.4.

**EDIT**

Using `qulonglong` as suggested

```
qulonglong p = (qulonglong)this;
return QString("0x%1").arg(p, 8, '0');
```

yields in a compiler error message [(error C2666)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyafzty4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Converting the pointer to a char will produce wrong result, as characters are only eight bits. Try `qulonglong` instead (or `qulong` if you are on a 32-bit system).

Comment: What do you think `qDebug` is doing when you pass `this` as a parameter with the format specifier in that literal string?

Comment: Sincerely: I have not much of a clue. I know that "%08x" represents an 8-bit hexadecimal value.

Comment: In the format string `"%08x"`, the "8" doesn't mean it's 8 bits, it means that the width will be 8 characters. The "0" means that if the value is not enough for 8 characters, it will be padded with the character '0'. I suggest you read more about `printf` and its formatting.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. The "x" actually makes the output hexadecimal. The "8 bit" remark was nonsense, sorry. "%08x" will output the number as zero-padded, 8-digit hex number, which represents 32 bit. So I guess for an x64 pointer this would read "%016x"?

Comment: Prefer C++ casts over c-style casts: `static_cast<unsigned long long>(this)` etc.

Comment: Better use: `qDebug("pointer of current object = %p", this);` or `qDebug() << "current object = " << this;`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using [QString::arg()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg-2):

```
MyClass *ptr = new MyClass();
QString ptrStr = QString( "0x%1" ).arg( reinterpret_cast<quintptr>(ptr), 
                    QT_POINTER_SIZE * 2, 16, QChar('0') );
```

It will use the correct type and size for pointers (`quintptr` and `QT_POINTER_SIZE`) and will always prefix `"0x"`.

**Notes:**
To prefix the value with zeros, the fourth parameter needs to be `QChar('0')`.
To output the correct number of digits, `QT_POINTER_SIZE` needs to be doubled (because each byte needs 2 hex digits).

Comment: Use quintptr instead?

Answer (score 14):

Why not simply use `QString & QString::sprintf ( const char * cformat, ... )`

```
QString t;
// QString::sprintf adds 0x prefix
t.sprintf("%08p", ptr);
```

Comment: Actually, `QString().sprintf("%08p", ptr)` seems to be the simplest way. The format `p` creates the '0x' itself.

Comment: Forgot that Qt does it right way ;) not sure but in vc printf implementation there is no 0x prefix

Comment: Qt 5 recommends [not to use `QString::sprintf()` and `QString::asprintf()` in new Qt code](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#asprintf).

Comment: Sure, but answer was about Qt 4.7

Comment: Worked in Qt 3.3.8 as well.

Comment: this is now `QString str; str.asprintf("%p",ptr);`

Comment: asprintf is not recommended anymore https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#asprintf

Answer (score 8):

[QTextStream](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html) appears to offer the functionality you seek, and operates simply on a `void*`.

```
const void * address = static_cast<const void*>(ptr);
QString addressString;
QTextStream addressStream (&addressString);
addressStream << address;
qDebug() << addressString;
```

Unlike the other approaches, it does not reference notions like the particular number "8" or casting to "qlonglong".  Seems less worrisome, and is much like the [prescribed method for std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850125/convert-this-pointer-to-string) *(though without getting `std::string` conversions involved)*

Answer (score 2):

You could do an intermediate step with `sprintf`:

```
QString pointer_to_qstring(void *ptr)
{
    char temp[16];
    sprintf(temp, "0x%08p", ptr);
    return QString(static_cast<char *>(temp));
}
```

Or through `ostringstream`:

```
QString pointer_to_qstring(void *ptr)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << ptr:
    return QString(oss.str().c_str());
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `static_cast` or the `c_str()` I don't believe.

Answer (score 1):

For me mostly it is enough to see if the pointer is the `nullptr`or if it has the same value as an other pointer. For those cases it is enough to convert the pointer to a number and then use `QString::number()`

```
Cat * cat = new Cat();
qDebug()<<QString::number((std::uintptr_t)(cat));;
```

Comment: Your answer's output isn't hexadecimal (use argument 16 in `QString::number()`), not starting with `0x` and not zero-padded (use `QString("0x%1").arg(pointer, length, 16, QChar('0'))`, as in @Ignitor s answer).

Comment: (I agree that using padded hexadecimal output is not neccessary to compare pointer values. But in hex comparing is easier because the strings are shorter. And my debugger (VS2012) always displays addresses in hex.)

Comment: That is what I am saying. For me it is not important to get in hex format and I wonder if the one that asked that questions needs the hex format at all.