# c++: Storing an adress as string

Tags: c++, string, pointers, casting

I'm trying to store the address of a pointer as a string. In other words, I want to insert the content of the bytes that make up the **address** into a char vector.

What is the best way of doing this?

I need a fully portable method, including for 64 bit system.

Comment: adding every character i.e address into vector?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850125/convert-this-pointer-to-string.

Comment: @Dineshkumar, is it clearer now?

Comment: If the pointer's value (i.e. the object's address) is "001AFA8C" - what would the desired output look like? A vector of chars can either contain the single characters of the hexadecimal representation ("8" and "C" etc) or the actual bytes as decimal numbers ("8C" as "140" etc).

Comment: @Niko, I haven't thought of the first option. Actually... both fit my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an array (or vector, if you prefer that) of the actual bytes of the address, this should do the trick:

```
int foo = 10;
int* bar = &foo;

// Interpret pointer as array of bytes
unsigned char const* b = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const*>(&bar);

// Copy that array into a std::array
std::array<unsigned char, sizeof(void*)> bytes;
std::copy(b, b + sizeof(void*), bytes.begin());
```

---

To get an array containing the hexadecimal representation split up into single characters (whatever sense that makes), I'd use a stringstream - as some of the others already suggested. You can also use snprintf to get a string representation of the address, but that's more the C-style way.

```
// Turn pointer into string
std::stringstream ss;
ss << bar;
std::string s = ss.str();

// Copy character-wise into a std::array (1 byte = 2 characters)
std::array<char, sizeof(void*) * 2> hex;
std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), hex.begin());
```

Comment: I'm just curious, what is the way to get the characters of the hexadecimal representation?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to do

```
char buf[sizeof(void*) * 2 + 3];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%p", /* the address here */ );
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Why 32? isn't it way bigger than needed?

Comment: @Subway it's too much but it will work on any platforms right now.  I am editing with a portable way.

Comment: 32-bit uses 8+1, 64-bit uses 16+1, so this method allows up to 128-bit, but it won't have a null-cap in that case. You could size the buffer according to the platform, e.g. `char buf[sizeof(size_t)*2+1]`.

Comment: @Guillaume it does? hmm, my usual reference site has failed me.

Comment: In that case I suggest this alternative format string: `snprintf( buf, sizeof(buf), "%*zx", sizeof(size_t) * 2, (size_t) myPointerHere );` which will not print the pointless `0x`.

Comment: @Dave I guess that depends if you want it or not.  If you want to get rid of it, I'd use "%*tx" because size_t does not guarantee that it will be big enough (even if it will work in practice)

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string serialized (std::to_string ((intptr_t) ptr));
```

Comment: Thanks Artem. Isn't there a preferable c++ casting than the c-style casting?

Comment: Subway, This is a matter of taste. Sometimes a less verbose version is easier to read. If you're a fan of different guidelines, feel free to use them.

Comment: Subway, intptr_t is a C style for that matter (from `stdint.h`). You can use `std::intptr_t` if you so wish.

Comment: thanks. I wan't asking about using std::intptr_t, but about using a c++ casting, like `reinterpret_cast` or one of the others. Could you please tell me which one fits this case?

Answer (score 1):

C++ way to dos this would be to use string streams

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    MyType object;
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string result;

    ss << &object; // puts the formatted address of object into the stream
    result = ss.str(); // gets the stream as a std::string

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void storeAddr(vector<string>& v,void *ptr)
{
    stringstream s;
    s << (void*)ptr ;
    v.push_back(s.str());
}
```

Comment: The cast here does nothing; it's casting from `void*` to `void*`