# Dynamic string with Hex value as "\3"

Tags: c++, string

i want to generate the string

```
std::string mystr("\3");
```

dynamically. Where number is get at run time.

How can i do it as its representing it hex?

```
int x = 5;
```

so string would be as "\5" but creation is dynamic.

Comment: `int x = 5;`
`char c = (char) (x & 0xff);`

Comment: Perhaps this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255366/how-can-i-append-data-to-a-stdstring-in-hex-format .

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

```
std::string s {5};

// OR

std::string s;
s += 5;

assert (s == std::string("\5"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast `x` to a `char` and then build a `string` using `stringstream`. [demo](http://ideone.com/5bu0ty)

```
int x = 65; // 'A'
stringstream ss;
string s;
ss << (char) (x & 0xff);
ss >> s;

return s;
```